# If the center $Z(G)$ has index $n$ in $G$, then every conjugacy class of $G$ has at most $n$ elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am looking at a proof for this, which basically starts off by looking at the conjugacy class of $x$, where $|cl_{G}(x)|=n$ and then claims we can complete the proof if we can create a surjective map from $cl_{G}(x)$ to the set of cosets of $Z(G)$.

I don't understand why doing this will complete the proof? The mapping, by the way, will be defined as $\phi(gZ(G))=gxg^{-1}$. Can someone please explain how this surjective mapping solves the problem?

Comment: I'm guessing $G$ is a group, then.

Comment: I'm not seeing where $|\operatorname{cl}_G(x)|=n$ is coming from.  Why do you know such an $x$ exists?  The goal seems to be to prove that $|\operatorname{cl}_G(x)|\leq n$, so the given equality satisfies the desired one.

Comment: Oh yes, $G$ is a group. And, $|cl_{G}(x)|=n$ because the index of the center of $G$ is $n$, which is the same as saying the number of cosets of the center in $G$ is $n$. We could denote the set of cosets by $\{gZ(G)|g \in G\}$, which has order $n=[G:Z(G)]$....oh, wait. Maybe I also don't understand either how this implies the order of the conjugacy class is $n,$ is it because the center is abelian which implies every one of its elements is in the conjugacy class?

Answer (score 4):

The size of the conjugacy class of $g \in G$ is the index of the centralizer of $g$:
$$
C(g)=\{x\in G : xg=gx \}
$$
The result follows because the center of $G$ is clearly contained in the centralizer of $g$.